# Copy a value to EditorFor ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

Using ASP.Net MVC. In Edit mode I have this :

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date) %>
    </div>
```

and I have a DatePicker using Jquery.

```
<rhp:DatePicker ID="DatePicker1" runat="server"></rhp:DatePicker>
```

and I can get the Text of date picker : DatePicker1.Text

When the user pick the date I want picked date to be copied to model.Date and save to database.
How can I do this?

Comment: Could you share the complete code for the  editor template for `model.Date`

Comment: public string Date { get; set; }

Comment: Not the model code. I meant the code for the editor template that renders a `string` type (because your `Date` property is of `string` type)

Comment: There is not such code. The type of Date is not important. Just I have a string field ( model.Date ) and a returned string from DatePicker. Just I want to know how to assign the returned code to model.Date :-D

Comment: Type of the `Date` does matter. The way `EditorFor` works is, framework looks for a partial view named after the type of the property (in your case `string`).

Comment: Why not just use the jQuery UI datepicker and hook it up to the editor template for `Model.Date`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a custom EditorTemplate, the easiest way would be to remove the `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)` and use your DatePicker as the editor:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <rhp:DatePicker ID="Date" runat="server"></rhp:DatePicker>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date) %>
</div>
```

Notice that the ID for the DatePicker control is`Date`, which should allow the model binder to bind the value to the `Date` property of your model.